# .NET Socket ReadAsync blocked during write loop Async / Await

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, async-await

I am writing a TCP server using Async / Await that needs to send a list of messages to connected clients, based on what it receives from each client. *Between each message* sent to the client, I need to:

1. wait for an acknowledgement/response then send the next messages
2. resend the command if no acknowledgement after 5 seconds

To do this, I am setting a `ResponseReceived` property on my ConnClient class when the expected response comes in. Then, in the `ConnClient.SendListAsync` routine, I am checking to see if the property has been changed after sending each command. However, incoming responses are not read until the `SendListAsync` sends all messages, as can be seen in my debug statements below:

```
Sending Initial Message.
Received response, generate list of 3 initial commands and send them.
SendListAsync 5 second timeout w/o response.
SendListAsync 5 second timeout w/o response.
SendListAsync 5 second timeout w/o response.
Received response.
Received response.
Received response.
```

**Question:** How can I properly prevent `ConnClient.SendListAsync` from blocking incoming reads?

```
public class Svr
{
    TcpListener listener;
    public async Task Listen(IPAddress iP, int port)
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(iP, port);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            ConnClient cc = new ConnClient(client);
            await Receive(ConnClient);
        }
    }

    async Task Receive(ConnClient cc)
    {
        var headerSize = sizeof(short);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4000];

        //Send initial msg
        await cc.socket.GetStream().WriteAsync(Strings.InitialMsg, 0, Strings.InitialMsg.Length); 

        while (true)
        {
            buffer = new byte[headerSize];
            if (!await ReadToBuffer(cc.socket.GetStream(), buffer, headerSize))
                return;

            var length = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[2] { buffer[1], buffer[0] }, 0 );
            buffer = new byte[length];

            if (!await ReadToBuffer(cc.socket.GetStream(), buffer, length))
                return;

            await DoSomethingBasedOnReceived(messageBuffer, cc);
        }
    }

    async Task<Boolean> ReadToBuffer(NetworkStream stream, byte[] buffer, int bytesToRead)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < bytesToRead)
        {
            var length = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, bytesToRead - offset);
            if (length == 0)
                return false;
            offset += length;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public async Task DoSomethingBasedOnReceived(byte[]  messageBuffer, ConnClient cc)
    {
        await SomeLogicToSetTheRRFlagIfMessageApplicable(messageBuffer, cc);
        List<byte[]> ListOfMessagesToSend = SomeLogicToDetermineListOfMessages(messageBuffer);
        await cc.SendListAsync(ListOfMessagesToSend);
    }
}
```

ConnClient Class, representing an individual connected client.

```
public class ConnClient
{
    public TcpClient socket { get; set; }
    public Boolean ResponseReceived { get; set; }
    public ConnClient (TcpClient cc)
    {socket = cc}

    public async Task SendListAsync(List<byte[]> messageList)
    {
        foreach (byte[] msg in messageList)
        {
            this.ResponseReceived = false;
            await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);

            int waitedSoFar = 0;
            while (waitedSoFar < 5000)
            {
                if (this.ResponseReceived == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
                waitedSoFar += 100;
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I need to: ... resend the command if no acknowledgement after 5 seconds"_ -- that is a _ridiculous_ requirement for a TCP-based implementation. TCP already implements data acknowledgements in the protocol. You should not try to add your own on top of that, and you _certainly_ should not be resending data when an ack fails to be returned. If the remote endpoint ever gets the resent data, it will now have to contend with _two copies_ of the same data.

Comment: Peter, are you suggesting the best way to go would be to simply close the connection to the client if an acknowledgement isn't received within the designated time frame?

Comment: _"are you suggesting the best way to go would be to simply close the connection"_ -- actually, no. I'm suggesting the best way to go would be _do nothing_. There are lots of reasons a response might be delayed, some of them recoverable, some of them not. In the recoverable scenarios, as long as you _do nothing_, TCP will recover for you. In the non-recoverable scenarios, as long as you _do nothing_, your connection will eventually fail with an exception naturally. Then and only then, would you close the socket. Once the exception occurs, you know that socket is of no use any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is you will not be able to accept new clients.

```
while (true)
{
        // accept the next connection
        TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

        // receive and send list
        ConnClient cc = new ConnClient(client);
        await Receive(ConnClient);

        // the loop cannot continue to receive the next connection 
        // until you have done with your receive
}
```

You will need to execute `Receive` independently so you can wait for the next connection, you can either call it without an `await` (which **will** run as an *async void*), or *offload* it to a new task .

**Remove the await**

```
Receive(ConnClient);
```

**Offloading**

```
Task.Run(() => Receive(ConnClient));
```

Your second problem is your client is held up while sending and will not be able to receive. Once again you will to either *offload*, or run without the *await*.

As [@PeterDuniho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538012/peter-duniho) mentions

> Given that the *OP* is already using `async`/`await`, and given that
>   `Receive()` is already *async*, there's no reason to use `Task.Run()`. It's
>   *fire-and-forget* either way (unless they change their code to store the
>   returned *task*), so they might as well just *fire-and-forget* the call to
>   `Receive()` as wrap it in a call to `Task.Run()`.

<sub>***Note*** : Creating a scalable client/server socket solution is not trivial, and i am not attempting to show this. However, it will solve your current problem.</sub>

Either way, be very mindful of errors. Since both the proposed solutions will run unobserved, exceptions will **need to be handled**

Comment: TheGeneral, I see your point regarding the `Listen` routine. I do believe that is an issue I need to correct. However, I still receive the timeout notifications within a single connection. Are you suggesting I should additionally call `ConnClient.SendListAsync` without an await?

Comment: @AliceSmith yeah, you need to run them independently. Just make sure you catch the exceptions.